# If statement to display cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

my question is, if it is possible to display a cell only if there is data present for a specific post. I'm thinking something along the line of this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
    if(![query includeKey:@"Photo"]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PFImageView *photo = (PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    photo.file = object[@"image"];
    [photo loadInBackground];

    return cell;
}
```

I've tried this but i can not get it to work every which way try, any help will be apreciated, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Cells represent your data model. If there's no data then don't report it in the `numberOfRowsInSection` data source method. Then no cell will be requested for it.

Comment: Yes, the way you do this is to adjust your data source.  It's too late to do it once you're in `cellForRow`.

Comment: What im trying to do is if the user wants to upload a story or a photo or both, what ever they choose to upload the section only returns the rows that have data present.

Comment: So, you represent that in your data source.  Your data source is conceptual, and is not required to be tied to the numbering of records in a database or whatever.

Comment: @rjsantiago77 I've tried to format your code as good as I can, but it was a bit confusing and far away from compiling. If it does not match your ideas, please edit accordingly. (Please try to maintain a good formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Tables need a model, and that model is almost always an array.  The datasource protocol's job is to ask about that array.

So what's in your array?  Sometimes nothing, because you haven't fetched the data for it yet, or because the user has no data that belongs there.  From your question, it sounds like sometimes your array has 1 element -- something representing a post or an image -- and sometimes your array has 2 elements -- something representing a post *and* an image.

Thinking this way lets you divide your work into two parts: (1) do a fetch and create an array that represents the current state, (2) implement a table that presents the state of that array to the user.

Lets start with the array (note this is pseudo-code, meant to illustrate the idea):

```
// in interface
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *model;

// in init
_model = [NSMutableArray array];

// sometime at or after viewDidAppear, update your model by querying parse
// I don't understand your parse data model, but you want some query
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // based on the parse objects returned, initialize model
        [self.model addObject: ...];

        // tell your table that the model has changed
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

With your array handled elsewhere, the datasource job is simpler:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.model.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // dequeue a cell, configure its subviews based on self.model[indexPath.row]
    // no parse code here.  aim to configure the cell strictly based on the model
    return cell;
}
```

Notice how the table view is ignorant of parse.com and the parse code is largely ignorant of the table view.